# How do I prepend a string to program output without waiting for the whole line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, sh

I have a script that runs a command on a remote server using SSH. I want to prepend the string `Remote:` to every line of the output, but I don't want each line to be delayed until the whole line is available. Here is the output from my command:

```
$ myproject-db-push my_database_name
Exporting from database... Done
Archiving data... Done
Uploading archive to remote... Done
Running install script on remote
Remote: Decompressing archive into temporary directory... Done
Remote: Using database: my_database_name
Remote: Dropping collections:
Remote:  - my_collection_foo
Remote:  - my_collection_bar
Remote: Importing new data... Done
```

In this case, I'm using `sed` like this:

```
echo "$INSTALLCMD" | ssh -T "deploy@$SERVER" | sed -u "s/^/Remote: /"
```

The problem is, as I explained, that no *partial* lines are printed to the screen. If I remove the `| sed` part, it works as expected. First this is written:

```
Importing new data...
```

And a few seconds later, the line is completed:

```
Importing new data... Done
```

I'm assuming `sed` is only able to work on a line-by-line basis. I tried setting it to unbuffered, but it still waits for whole lines. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, because all those utillities (`sed`, `awk`, `grep`) are line buffered. That means they print the output only when the line has finished (a newline has appreaed). They cannot read the input character by character.

So for testing I made a small sequence, that simulates your behaviour:

```
{ 
  echo -n "first task: "
  sleep 2
  echo "done"
  echo -n "second task: "
  sleep 2
  echo "done"
}
```

As in your question, it prints `first task:` and after 2 seconds `done`. Try it yourself by copying it in your terminal.

**Solution:**

Add the following behind your command:

```
IFS=
command | { x=1; while IFS= read -d'' -s -N 1 char; do
  [ $x ] && printf "Remote: "
  printf "$char"
  unset x
  [ "$char" == "
" ] && x=1
done; }
```

**Explanation:**

The `read` builtin of `bash` can read input character by character. The part `read -d'' -s -N 1 char` disables the delimiter `-d''`, activates the silent mode `-s` and reads only 1 character a time `-N 1` into the variable `$char`. Then the command checks if the variable `$x` exists. If yes, we are in a new line and we print the "prefix". Then print the character. Unset `$x`. Then last statement checks if the character is a newline. If it's a newline set `$x` to `1` and in the next loop, the "prefix" will be printed.

The whole thing can be tested, when you concatente the two sequences:

```
{ 
  echo -n "first task: "
  sleep 2
  echo "done"
  echo -n "second task: "
  sleep 2
  echo "done"
} | { x=1; while IFS= read -d'' -s -N 1 char; do
  [ $x ] && printf "Remote: "
  printf "$char"
  unset x
  [ "$char" == "
" ] && x=1
done; }
```

Comment: Oh, neat! I had planned on doing basically this, but in Ruby, if no better solutions came up. I didn't know this could be done so easily using only Bash.

Comment: @Hubro I changed the syntax a bit, now it prepends the first line too.

Comment: I've made a small utility for appending/prepending text to lines using your answer: [apline](https://gist.github.com/Hubro/d0f05c010edad6465326). It's probably not perfect, but it appears to work flawlessly in my few use cases so far.

Comment: @Hubro nice, works like a charm!